# Regex catch from the hash sign "#" to the next white space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script line this :

```
#type1 this is the text of the note
```

I've tried this bu didn't workout for me :

```
^\#([^\s]+)
```

I watch to catch `type` in other words I to get whats between the hash sign "#" and the next white space, excluding the hash "#" sign, and the string that I want to catch is alphanumeric string.

Comment: Okay, and where's your attempt? We can help you fix it, but we're not gonna write it for you (unless you hire us ;) )

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've aded the attempt that I've made

Comment: Why is the expected ouptut `type` and not `type1` considering you want to capture everything between `#` and the next space? Your code should work as it is: https://regex101.com/r/uxfyFN/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

`/^\#([^\s]+)+(.*)$/`

Answer (score 1):

With the regex functionality provided by Javascript:

```
exec_result = /#(\w*)/.exec('#whatever string comes here');
```

I believe `exec_result[1]` should be the string you want.

The return value of `exec()` method could be found over here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 0):

You're really close:

```
/^\#(\w+)\s/
```

The \w matches any letters or numbers (and underscores too). And the space should be outside the matching group since I guess you don't want to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

To get an alphanumeric match (which will get you type1), instead of the negated character class `[^\s]` which matches not a whitespace character, you could use a character class and specify what you want to match like `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Then use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not a non-whitespace char:

```
^#([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bYHTxf/1)

Your match is in the first capturing group. Note that you don't have to escape the `\#`

For example using the case insensitive flag `/i`

```js
const regex = /^#([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?!\S)/i;
const str = `#type1 this is the text of the note`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

If you only want to match type, you might use:

```
^#([a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KwYvxt/1)

```js
const regex = /^#([a-z]+)[a-z0-9]*(?!\S)/i;
const str = `#type1 this is the text of the note`;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```